# How to separate Web API from MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have several MVC Projects and I don't want to use my controllers in a RESTful manner.  I want the controllers to call a separate REST Service.  This service is separate because we will be building HTTP services that can be consumed not only by MVC web clients but other mobile devices.

I created several individual MVC 5 projects and one Web API project

1) My question is that I am using ajax calls to populate the views.  Should the ajax requests call my MVC Controller and then have my MVC Controller call the Web Api via webclient/httpclient?  or  Should I just make ajax request directly to the Web Api Controller bypassing the MVC Controller?

2) Most importantly, If 99% of my requests are AJAX requests, should I even use an MVC 5 Project?  I am not returning views back, just data.  Should I just use a regular ASP.net page and make Ajax calls to the Web API Service?  or is it acceptable to use .net MVC in this manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 2 cents:

I think, it is better to call the web api service directly through client side ajax request to get the data.

You can skip both asp.net and asp.net mvc 5 project, and create asp.net web api empty project, and add html pages in it.

I would suggest to use single page application structure/design. following sample project may be helpful in this regard.

https://github.com/MarlabsInc/webapi-angularjs-spa

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463786.aspx

Comment: But I want my Web API to be separate from my other projects so that it can be consumed by mobile devices and any other 3rd party client.

Comment: @tdw how much development you already done? what if you re-factor/move existing api controller to new web api project, and this structure will allow you to separate the web api logic from asp.net mvc project.
Moreover, if u r starting from scratch the above proposed solution by me(Answer) should work fine.
Lastly, I answered considering you description, and my understanding of it. Please correct me if I misunderstood, and explain further.

Comment: I do have web api controller as a web api project.  And I have several MVC projects that consume the web api.  What you are suggesting that I do is to create an asp.net web api and add html pages to it, but we have mobile apps and 3rd party vendors that need to consume our Web API.  That's why I wanted to make it standalone.

Comment: OK, you can call your web api REST api endpoints irrespective of the solution structure we discussed above. Only thing is to make sure that that CORS is enabled.
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api
I suggested to use html page because it seems that you are not taking any benefits by use of razor or aspx view engine. Also, from the description above that you just return data from server I concluded that why not go for single page application then with html pages. Hope it helps.